# Construct a path and calculate the integrals

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Assume $G = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: \vert z \vert < 1 \quad and \quad Re(z) + Im(z) > 1 \}$. Construct a path $ \gamma: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ with $\gamma([a,b])=\partial G$ and calculate $\int_\gamma Im(z) dz $ and $\int_\gamma Re(z)dz$. Furthermore  calculate and interprete $\int_\gamma \bar{z}dz$.

Hint: Use the Leibniz sector formula.

My problem is that I'm not sure if I'm understanding this exercise right because I didn't use the sector formula for my result.
In my opinion $G$ is a circular segment in the first quadrant of the complex plane. Therefore I can easily construct the path:

$\gamma_1: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, t \mapsto t+ i(1-t)$

$\gamma_2: [0,\pi/2] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, t \mapsto \cos(t)+ i\sin(t)$

With these paths the results of my integrals are (results edited):

$\int_\gamma Im(z) dz = \frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{\pi}{2})$ and $\int_\gamma Re(z)dz = \frac{i}{2}(\frac{\pi}{2}-1)$

Since $\bar{z}=Re(z)-iIm(z)$ I can write:
$\int_\gamma \bar{z}dz = \int_\gamma Re(z)-iIm(z)dz = \int_\gamma Re(z) dz - i\int_\gamma Im(z) dz=i(\frac{\pi}{2}-1)$

Comment: Here is another hint: do your own homework. If you need help, ask specifically about the help you need. Don't just lazily give us the whole problem.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't mean to offend someone. Of course I tried to solve the exercise on my own - i edited now.

Comment: I apologize for being grumpy there. I can only plead a shortage of sleep. But the basic message is true. If you simply post a problem as you did, there are many who will downvote you and vote to close the question with reason being so broadly stated that it will be unlikely you will realize the problem is that you haven't shown any attempt yourself. The people here are passionate about math. Therefore we like to help others improve their own understanding. But we hate when people try ot use us to avoid having to learn it themselves. So it is best to always show you are trying to learn.

Comment: I see what you mean and I totally agree. Thanks for your help and time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name "Leibnitz Sector Formula" is not one I am familiar with (almost certainly know the formula, but not this name for it). And attempts to search for it online turned up only a few mentions, none of which actually stated what it was. So I am unable to address the point of the hint.

You are correct about the boundary. But I do not get the same answer you did. For $\gamma_1$, note that $\gamma_1'(t)= 1-i$, so $$\int_{\gamma_1}Re(z)dz = \int_0^1(t)(1-i)dt$$

$\gamma_2'(t) = -\sin t + i\cos t$, so 
$$\int_{\gamma_2}Re(z)dz = \int_0^{\pi/2}\cos t(-\sin t + i\cos t)dt$$
These do not simplify to $\frac {\sqrt 2}2 + 1$

Comment: Thanks I edited my results in the question above. The sector formula was for calculating the area of $G$ which is $\frac{1}{2}(frac{\pi}{2}-1)$